# Enabling ECMAScript modules in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm experimenting with ECMAScript modules in Node.js 12 but I'm struggling with. Following the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html) just by adding the *top-level field "type" with a value of "module"* it should be enough to keep using the extension `.js` in this Node.js version but I can not find why is not working as expected. Am I missing something?

```
$ node --version
v12.14.1
```

```
$ cat package.json 
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node test.js"
  }
}
```

```
$ npm start

> app@ start /usr/src/app
> node test.js

/usr/src/app/test.js:1
import { myFunction } from './module.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

```
$ cat test.js
import { myFunction } from './module.js';

myFunction();
```

```
$ cat module.js 
function myFunction() {
  console.log('hello from module');
}

export { myFunction };
```

Comment: You are using Node.js 12 but reading the documentation of Node.js 13. *Edit*: Now that you link to the proper documentation, you do not use the `--experimental-modules` flag as stated in the docs.

Comment: You are right @str. My previous comment did not appear :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_code_import_code_statements

Version 12 docs for that import statement show that you can only import the default export via `import ... from ...`

So `import myFunction from './module.js';` would work if you exported myFunction as `export default myFunction;`

Comment: That only affects "CommonJS files or packages", not ESM as in the question.

Comment: Also worth noting that this is how it works in previous versions of node as well.